# How to reduce size of bottleneck features of intermediate layer of VGG16?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to connect the layer ***c0nv4_3*** of **vgg16** network instead of ***conv5_3*** to the RPN network of Faster R-CNN. [Here](https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn/blob/master/lib/nets/vgg16.py) is the python code of vgg16 network. I have changed these lines:

```
def _image_to_head(self, is_training, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope(self._scope, self._scope, reuse=reuse):
      net = slim.repeat(self._image, 2, slim.conv2d, 64, [3, 3],
                          trainable=False, scope='conv1')
      net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], padding='SAME', scope='pool1')
      net = slim.repeat(net, 2, slim.conv2d, 128, [3, 3],
                        trainable=False, scope='conv2')
      net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], padding='SAME', scope='pool2')
      net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, 256, [3, 3],
                        trainable=is_training, scope='conv3')
      net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], padding='SAME', scope='pool3')
      net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, 512, [3, 3],
                        trainable=is_training, scope='conv4')
      net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], padding='SAME', scope='pool4')
      net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, 512, [3, 3],
                        trainable=is_training, scope='conv5')

    self._act_summaries.append(net)
    self._layers['head'] = net

return net
```

to:

```
def _image_to_head(self, is_training, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope(self._scope, self._scope, reuse=reuse):
      net = slim.repeat(self._image, 2, slim.conv2d, 64, [3, 3],
                          trainable=False, scope='conv1')
      net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], padding='SAME', scope='pool1')
      net = slim.repeat(net, 2, slim.conv2d, 128, [3, 3],
                        trainable=False, scope='conv2')
      net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], padding='SAME', scope='pool2')
      net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, 256, [3, 3],
                        trainable=is_training, scope='conv3')
      net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], padding='SAME', scope='pool3')
      net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, 512, [3, 3],
                        trainable=is_training, scope='conv4')

    self._act_summaries.append(net)
    self._layers['head'] = net

return net
```

As seen above, I removed the **conv5 and pool4 layers**; because my objects are small and I hoped to get better results, but the results got worse. I think I need to add a **deconv layer** to the end of conv4? Or there is another way?

thanks

Comment: Are you using pre-trained models? and want to extract bottleneck features?

Comment: @PramodPatil yes I am trying to use **vgg net** as pretrained model, but instead of conv5_3, I would like to get the output (head layer) from conv4_3, so the resolution of the feature map would be higher. Am I supposed to do anything else here? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are methods too, for reducing the length of bottleneck features.

**Why not to add deconv**:

- You will initialize deconv layer with random values
- You are not finetuning the network, you are just making forward pass through the network.
- So the output of deconv will randomize your features of conv4

**Pooling Layers:**

- Average pooling(based on the window size, it will return average of that window). So if lets say window(2,2) with values[3,2,4,3] will result into only one value: 6
- MaxPool(based on the window size, it will result maximum value of that window). So if lets say window(2,2) with values[3,2,4,3] will result into only one value: 3

Check out pooling layers [here](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/)